# how to select first and last data from date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql query:

```
WITH Cte AS
(
    SELECT DateTime,

        rn1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTime ASC),
        rn2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
    FROM
        Test
    WHERE
        Username = 'ME'
        AND DateTime > '2016-01-05'
        AND DateTime < '2016-01-06'
)
SELECT * FROM Cte WHERE rn1 = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Cte WHERE rn2 = 1
```

With this query I'm successfully getting the first and last data in **5th January 2016**

But how can I get the first and last data, for example, from **5th January** to **8th January**?

That is, I'd like to get the first and last data from 5th January, then the first and last data from 6th January, and then the first and last data from 7th January, and then finally the first and last data from 8th January.

UPDATE
[image]

as you can see, the order is kind of mess
I want it look like this

[image]

Comment: Try adding `PARTITION BY CAST(DateTime AS DATE)` in the `OVER` clause.

Comment: thnks, this is what I lokking for, maybe you can post it as answer so I can accept it

Comment: Done. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first and last data for each day from Jan 5 to 8, you need to add a `PARTITION BY` on your `OVER` clause:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT 
        DateTime,
        rn1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(DateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY DateTime ASC),
        rn2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(DateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
    FROM Test
    WHERE
        Username = 'ME'
        AND DateTime >= '20160105'
        AND DateTime < '20160109'
)
SELECT * FROM Cte WHERE rn1 = 1 OR rn2 = 1
```

---

EDIT:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        CAST(DateTime AS DATE),
        DateTime,
        rn1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(DateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY DateTime ASC),
        rn2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(DateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
    FROM Test
    WHERE
        Username = 'ME'
        AND DateTime >= '20160105'
        AND DateTime < '20160109'
)
SELECT * FROM Cte WHERE rn1 = 1 OR rn2 = 1
ORDER BY CAST(DateTime AS DATE)
```

Comment: by using this query,  if the date range is only 2 or 3 days, it's good, but if the range is about 1 month, the row is a mess, is there any way so the data could be group by date?

Comment: You can add `(CAST DateTime AS DATE)` in the `SELECT`.

Comment: I've add picture in my question showing the mess, and I try using Cast, and no luck

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: I want it look like my second picture

Comment: why bother with the CTE now? it can be done as a simple derived table as there is no second query to union

Comment: Derived table and a non recursive CTE is basically the same.